# Generic methods and interfaces in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, generics, c++-cli

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension in C++/CLI. To control editor outlining I need to implement `ITaggerProvider` interface, and here is my attempt to do that:

```
private ref class MyTagger : ITagger<IOutliningRegionTag^>
{
public:
    virtual event EventHandler<SnapshotSpanEventArgs^>^ TagsChanged;
    virtual IEnumerable<ITagSpan<IOutliningRegionTag^>^>^ GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection ^spans)
    {
        return nullptr;
    }
};

[Export(ITaggerProvider::typeid)]
[TagType(IOutliningRegionTag::typeid)]
[ContentType("text")]
private ref class OutliningTaggerProvider : ITaggerProvider
{
public:
    generic<typename T> where T : ITag
    virtual ITagger<T>^ CreateTagger(ITextBuffer^ buffer)
    {
        return dynamic_cast<ITagger<T>^>(gcnew MyTagger()); // Error here
    }
};
```

However, the above code does not compile:

```
error C3214: 'T': invalid type argument for generic parameter 'T' of generic 'Microsoft::VisualStudio::Text::Tagging::ITagSpan', does not meet constraint 'Microsoft::VisualStudio::Text::Tagging::ITag ^'
note: see reference to class generic instantiation 'Microsoft::VisualStudio::Text::Tagging::ITagger<T>' being compiled
```

I'm not an expert in C++/CLI, but to my understanding the code is correct.

Here is the equivalent C# code which compiles fine:

```
internal class MyTagger : ITagger<IOutliningRegionTag>
{
    public event EventHandler<SnapshotSpanEventArgs> TagsChanged;
    public IEnumerable<ITagSpan<IOutliningRegionTag>> GetTags(NormalizedSnapshotSpanCollection spans)
    {
        return null;
    }
}

[Export(typeof(ITaggerProvider))]
[TagType(typeof(IOutliningRegionTag))]
[ContentType("text")]
internal class OutliningTaggerProvider : ITaggerProvider
{
    public ITagger<T> CreateTagger<T>(ITextBuffer buffer) where T : ITag
    {
        return new MyTagger() as ITagger<T>;
    }
}
```

What is the problem with C++/CLI version? Maybe I'm missing something, or is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Does your 'IOutliningRegionTag' implement 'ITag' interface in C++ code?

Comment: @Evk IOutliningRegionTag is derived from ITag